# elisp message-box: can I include newlines in the text, and if so, how?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Using the `message-box` fn, I can display a modal dialog.

I know this is annoying and not always a good user experience. Flymake's use of the `message-box` to warn when a flymake check has failed, seems a good example of that. 
But put the user experience issue aside for the purposes of this question. Assume that I am sensible enough to use message-box responsibly.

How can I format the text displayed by the message box? The simplest case is, how can I tell message box to display multiple lines of text. If I have a longish message, it results in a very wide message box.  (Another UI problem exhibited in the Flymake usage).

See here for an example. this code:

```
(message-box (concat "You need to get an \"api key\".<NL>"
             "Then, set it in your .emacs with the appropriate statement."))
```

results in this UI:

[image]

I'd like a newline in place of the `<NL>`.  I tried using `\n` and `\r` and `\r\n`, none of those worked. I also tried `\x000D` and `\x000A`.

Even better than simple line breaks, I'd like to be able to format the text. Italic, bold, or whatever. Are there options?  Nothing is mentioned in the doc on this.

I looked in the source to try to figure this out but could not find message2, which is called by message-box, and I'm not sure I'd learn anything anyway by just looking at source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\n`.  That does the trick:

```
(message-box (concat "You need to get an \"api key\".\n"
                     "Then, set it in your .emacs with the appropriate statement."))
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't for me., for some reason . As I was posting the question I thought, *Well I'd better show the case with \n* but, I didn't.  Then I tried `\r\n`, same result. I ran out of things to try.

Comment: @Cheeso, Emacs version?  Have you tried running Emacs with -q? --no-site-init?

Comment: Hmmm, well... this may be the problem `This is GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)`.  Windows.  I just tried with -q and same result.

Comment: If that's the case, I could special case the Windows environment and use an alternative to display a message box there.

Comment: @Cheeso It fails for me on Windows as well (works on Linux).  I'd try `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Sorry.

Comment: No apologies!  Thanks for the help in tracking it down.

Answer (score 0):

hack workaround on Windows for bug #11138.

```
(defun multiline-message-box (msg)
  "display a multiline message box on Windows.

According to bug #11138, when passing a message with newlines to
`message-box' on Windows, the rendered message-box appears all on
one line.

This function can work around that problem.
"
  (flet ((ok (&optional p1 &rest args) t))

    (let ((parts (split-string msg "\n"))
          (menu-1 (make-sparse-keymap "Attention"))
          c)

      (define-key menu-1 [menu-1-ok-event]
        `(menu-item ,(purecopy "OK")
                    ok
                    :keys ""))
      (define-key menu-1 [separator-1] menu-bar-separator)

      ;; add lines in reverse order
      (setq c (length parts))
      (while (> c 0)
        (setq c (1- c))
        (define-key menu-1 (vector (intern (format "menu-1-fake-event-%d" c)))
          `(menu-item ,(purecopy (nth c parts))
                      nil
                      :keys ""
                      :enable t)))
      (x-popup-menu t menu-1))))


(multiline-message-box "Hello!\nI must be going!\nThis is line 3.")
```